# Android Worker: ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE not working

Tags: android, kotlin

I am enqueuing a `Worker` in my `enqueuePeriodicDownloadTask` method with the `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy` set to `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE`.

```kotlin
fun enqueuePeriodicDownloadTask(
    url: String
) {
    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    val periodicRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NewsWorker>(
        30, TimeUnit.MINUTES
    ).setConstraints(
        Constraints(
            requiresBatteryNotLow = true
        )
    ).setInputData(
        inputData = workDataOf(
            NewsWorker.URL to url,
            NewsWorker.SOFT_MODE to true,
        )
    )
    workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        PERIODIC_NEWSWORKER_NAME,
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE,
        periodicRequest.build()
    )
    Log.i(LogKeys.BASIC_KEY, "Enqueued periodic task")
}
```

According to the offical [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/update-work) this policy should behave like this:

> For example, when using enqueueUniquePeriodicWork with a PeriodicWorkRequest, you can initialize the new PeriodicWorkRequest with the ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE policy. If there is a pending PeriodicWorkRequest with the same unique name, WorkManager updates it to the new specification. Following this workflow, it is not necessary to use updateWork().

However, if I call `enqueuePeriodicDownloadTask` with another URL the `worker` is called immediately. I would expect the `worker` to be updated but run at the already scheduled time and not immediately:

> It preserves enqueue time, e.g. if a work was run 3 hours ago and had 8 hours long period, after the update it would be still eligible for run in 5 hours, assuming that periodicity wasn't updated.

Why does `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE` behave differently in my case?

Comment: I have the same behaviour

Comment: What about [**`ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.CANCEL_AND_REENQUEUE`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy#CANCEL_AND_REENQUEUE)?  In my case, when the Worker stopped and I tried to relaunch it, I was using `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE` and it didn't work, putting `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.CANCEL_AND_REENQUEUE` did start again.

Comment: Same here, I don't understand this at all. I'm also using setInitialDelay but it gets completely ignored and the work si started right away.